# Remove markdown code block from python string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove markdown code blocks from the following string:

````
Problem with encoding a very large BigInteger or BigDecimal without fraction

We have an issue to encode a very large BigDecimal. For example, when I tried to encode _7.533938258014959827307132527342E+545_ I got the following error:

``` java
Error com.n1analytics.paillier.EncodeException: Input value cannot be encoded.
at com.n1analytics.paillier.StandardEncodingScheme.encode(StandardEncodingScheme.java:115)
at com.n1analytics.paillier.StandardEncodingScheme.encode(StandardEncodingScheme.java:239)
...
```

The reason why I got the error is as follows:
````

I've tried:

````py
txt = re.sub('(```[a-z]*\n[\s\S]*?\n```)', '', txt) # https://regex101.com/r/aA5bI3/3
txt = re.sub('(```.+?```)', '', txt)  # https://regex101.com/r/aA5bI3/3
````

Even though I saw some of these regex at https://coderwall.com/p/r6b4xg/regex-to-match-github-s-markdown-code-blocks and https://regex101.com/r/aA5bI3/3, I had no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern almost works, but in the example data there is a space before  `java`

If the spaces and the chars a-z are the only acceptable characters after the backticks and they are optional, you could match optional whitespace chars without a newline `[^\S\r\n]*`

The pattern could look like

````
```[^\S\r\n]*[a-z]*\n.*?\n```
````

Instead of using `[\s\S]*?` you can use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make the dot match a newline.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIHoIA/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0mrcJe)

For example

````
txt = re.sub(r"```[^\S\r\n]*[a-z]*\n.*?\n```", '', txt, 0, re.DOTALL)
````

---

If the backticks always begin at the start of the string, and also end at the start of the string, you could make the pattern a bit more efficient matching all the lines in between that do not start with 3 backticks using a negative lookahead to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

As the pattern uses an anchor, you should use the `re.MULTILINE` flag.

````
^```[^\S\r\n]*[a-z]*(?:\n(?!```$).*)*\n```
````

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- ```` ``` ```` Match 3 backticks
- `[^\S\r\n]*[a-z]*` Match optional spaces without a newline and optional chars a-z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - ```` \n(?!```$) ```` Match a newline and assert that the line does not start with 3 backticks
  - `.*` If that is the case, match the whole line
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times to match all lines
- ```` \n``` ```` Match a newline and 3 backticks

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DcjApD/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VC0jet)

For example

````
txt = re.sub(r"^```[^\S\r\n]*[a-z]*(?:\n(?!```$).*)*\n```", '', txt, 0, re.MULTILINE)
````

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply use this regex

````
```.*?```
````

with single-line option enabled

Example: https://regex101.com/r/fubH7e/1